# how to pass threshold to BigQuery ML model when deployed to vertex ai

Tags: tensorflow, google-bigquery, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am exporting a BigQuery ML model to cloud storage and then importing the resulting tensorflow model to vertex ai.

The deployed model uses a threshold of 0.5.

If I were doing prediction in BigQuery, I would have used ML.predict with STRUCT(0.05 as THRESHOLD). How can I tell Vertex AI to similarly pass THRESHOLD to all input requests?

Comment: Hi @Lak, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer

Answer (score 0):

As per the BigQuery ML [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-predict#threshold), the threshold value is only available for binary classification models.

When deploying the exported model to Vertex AI, you can proceed with getting online predictions from it as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/classification-regression/get-online-predictions#online-prediction).

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/classification-regression/interpret-results), the output of online prediction contains the confidence score value, which needs to be interpreted by the client in your code. You can just filter the prediction results by the threshold value.

Comment: My question is asking for a server-side solution. It is poor practice to put ML postprocessing operations in client code.  The ideal threshold changes every time a new model is deployed, so this needs to done server-side.